# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError JNI error on Windows

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I try to run my java with native method on mac and windows.

class with native method:

```
public class NativeMethods {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("nativeLib");
    }

    public static native void printFromJni();
}
```

class with main method:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

        NativeMethods.printFromJni();
    }

}
```

JNI header:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_sdk_NativeMethods */

#ifndef _Included_com_sdk_NativeMethods
#define _Included_com_sdk_NativeMethods
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/*
 * Class:     com_sdk_NativeMethods
 * Method:    printFromJni
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_sdk_NativeMethods_printFromJni
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_sdk_NativeMethods_printFromJni
(JNIEnv *env, jclass class){
    printf("hello from jni. \n");
}
```

If i compile c files on MAC:

```
gcc -o libNativeLib.so -shared -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/include  nativeLib.c -lc
```

and run:

```
java Demo
```

It's work correct.

But if i compile c files on Windows:

```
gcc -o nativeLib.dll -shared -I"C:\P
rogram Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\include" nativeLib.c
 -std=c99 -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\include\win32"
```

i get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sdk.Nati
veMethods.printFromJni()V
        at com.sdk.NativeMethods.printFromJni(Native Method)
        at Demo.main(Demo.java:9)
```

if i compile c files on mac(with -m32 flag) and copy library on Windows i get error:

```
Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x7) on
 a IA 32-bit platform
```

Where is a problem? Please help.

I found **SOLUTION**:

```
gcc -Wall -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -Wl,--kill-at -I[Java_HOME]/include -I[Java_HOME]/include/win32 -shared -o Sample1.dll Sample1.c
```

Comment: Don't compile on mac.. Compile on Windows itself. It should work fine that way only...

Answer (score 0):

First create the object of Nativemethods class in your main class and then try to run the function. 
Tell me if still error persists. I will run in my system and let you know what actually is the error.

And by the way both classes are in same file ?
Because if not then while compiling java program you need to be careful about getting right compilation while generating header file .. (That step worked out okay for you right ?)

**Also while running javafile give path for dll file.**

```
-Djava.library.path = "Write path"
```